# Import ES6 module from npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I created and published my first npm package. This package contains JS in ES6 syntax and is transpiled to ES5 with webpack and babel.

Now I want to use this npm package but it fails with following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\dev\git\open-source\test\node_modules\chokidar'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./node_modules/technology-radar/webpack.config.js
 @ ./sample/app.js
```

For usage I have the following (minimal) set of files

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "webpack": "^3.5.6",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "3.5.17",
  "technology-radar": "^1.0.3"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        sample: './sample/app.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "sample")
                ],
                test: /\.js$/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'sample/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ],
    devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

sample/app.js

```
import Radar from 'technology-radar';

var radar = new Radar("#techradarContainer");
radar.render();
```

I don't know if there is in the usage or in the npm package itself.
The sourcecode of the package is available on github at https://github.com/raman-nbg/techradar. The npm package is available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/technology-radar.

The class which should be export (as defined as entry point in the webpack.config.js of the package) is defined src/Radar.js with `export default class Radar { ... }`. The entry point is defined as

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "technology-radar": "./src/Radar.js",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is this module for use on node or on the browser? If it relies on the `fs` module in order to work, consider adding the option `target: 'node'` in your webpack config to ensure webpack ignores built-in modules like `fs`, `path`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how publishing and using packages works.

Ignoring Webpack entirely, a standard `npm` module has `main` set to the JS file that is the root of your package, and generally packages published to `npm` are compiled with Babel *before* being published. Usually before publishing `technology-radar`, you'd use a package like `babel-cli` with

```
babel src -d lib
```

to compile everything in the `src` directory into ES5 inside `lib`. Then 
your [`package.json#main`](https://github.com/raman-nbg/techradar/blob/fa2c30491d57e48ad6b4fd0389da4f34bedb7feb/package.json#L5) value should be

```
"main": "./lib/index.js"
```

or whichever package is the conceptual root of your package. That could be `Radar.js` in your case, but it's hard to tell.

Because your `main` is set to `webpack.config.js`, when you run Webpack inside your actual application, you are trying to bundle Webpack *itself* for use on in a browser, which does not work because it is a Node application.

If you've done the above and have a `technology-radar` package that is already processed with Babel, the configuration of your `sample` application is pretty much what you already have.

Comment: Thank you! I am really confused about the combination of npm, webpack, babel ...
I changed the value in package.json#main. Now I can build/transpile my sample application. But in the Browser I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: _technologyRadar2.default is not a constructor` for the line `var radar = new Radar("#techradarContainer");`
I think I have some error in exporting the Radar class (of the npm package itself) or in importing it in the sample application.